# How do I create a region/zone map for the web?

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, sitemap

I'm looking to create my own region/zone maps for an internal web application for layouts of buildings and yard layouts. I want the map to essentially be something like this: 
http://createaclickablemap.com/

[image]

However, it doesn't have to be "clickable" or any user interaction at all. I will be colouring each zone and I can't just make a big jpeg image because different regions and zones will change fill colours programatically based on certain criteria.

I have no idea where to begin, how does one create something like this for the web using PHP, CSS and JavaScript or are there any tools out there that do this already?

Comment: Use something off-the-shelf for this.  The Google Visualization API is very good, but there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deal with a lot of maps these days and I would be lost without this:

http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/

Trace/convert your jpg to a vector image then open it in Illustrator and convert it to javascript using ai2canvas.
You may then manipulate the the image with javascript.

If you need to cater for older browsers, it's quite easy to create a flash version too.

Comment: Oh nice, we already have all our maps in .ai format so this might just work out great.

Comment: Make sure all your paths are optimised wih the minimum of overlap as ALL paths are added to the javascript.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention, the latest adobe flash does all of this for you.
Although you probably know this  by now.